# MongoDB aggregate returns random results every time (PyMongo)

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I've met a weird behavior of `pymongo.aggregate`.

I'm using `pymongo collection.aggregate()` to get results. The command returns new results every time even with simple request.

```
In [8]: print([i['_id'] for i in col.aggregate([
   ...:     {'$match': {'$text': {'$search': 'mark'}}},
   ...:     {'$limit':2}])])
['CA 990342008', 'TX 16854869']

In [9]: print([i['_id'] for i in col.aggregate([
   ...:     {'$match': {'$text': {'$search': 'mark'}}},
   ...:     {'$limit':2}])])
['TX 8210259', 'CA 993322075']
```

Would be happy if someone points me to what I've missed in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like most databases the order of returned documents is arbitrary unless a specific order is requested. This is done for optimisation purposes; as soon as the internal engine has 2 documents that match (in your example) there is no need to do anything else so that's why you might see different results.

In MongoDB you can request a specific order using the `.sort()` operator, or in the case of your example, a `$sort` aggregation pipeline stage.

Comment: I have 18M records and `sort` against all data is too expensive. Thanks for answer.